Opamp output current spec, what is meant by VDROPOUT?
I am using ADA4077 in one of my application. I was checking it's output current specification.
It is given below.

My question is,
What you mean by VDROPOUT here?
What is the significance of VDROPOUT and when do I need to consider that in my design?


What is the significance of VDROPOUT

It's similar to the drop-out voltage specified for a voltage regulator in that the more output current you wish to supply, the greater the input voltage will need to be to keep the output in regulation.
If you look at the relevant page in the data sheet you linked you will get this broader information about the op-amp's ability to drive its output close to the supply rails: -

Inside the red boxes (that I have added) you can see that for a +/- 5 volt supply, the output voltage is guaranteed to swing to within 1.5 volts of either supply rail when the load current is 1 mA at normal ambient temperatures. When the ambient temperature is the full range, a 1 mA load (sourcing or sinking) may impose a 1.8 volt limit on the output reaching the supply rails. This may/can also be referred to as the drop-out voltage.
In the green box is the limit when the load current is 10 mA and the temperature is normal ambient. There are a series of graphs later on in the data sheet that provide further information. Here is one of them that shows the "sink" current of the output for a supply of +/- 5 volts: -


when I need to consider that in my design

You need to consider it always; if you expect the output to reach the full supply voltage range, it won't and, it'll get worse the more current that the output is expected to handle.

In the graph X axis is current and Y axis is dropout voltage but I can see 100,10K,1K at the Y axis

@Confused the unit is mV, so 1k is 1000mV, ie 1V. k means one thousand, not necessarily resistance.

Digital outputs are not ideal voltage sources. Every output has some output resistance, which causes the output voltage to drop when current is increased.
VDROPOUT is the max. reduction of voltage at the output when the output is loaded with the specified current (±10mA in this case). From this, you can calculate the maximum output resistance of this output: R_max = U_max/I < 120 Ohms.
